# Android NDK doesn't include ltdl

Tags: android, android-ndk, autotools

I'm trying to build a linux library for Android, but it seems that libtool for the android gcc toolchain doesn't include ltdl, the dynamic loader.  Is there a system-related reason for this, or is it just not there?

How would I go about incorporating the ltdl from www.gnu.org/software/libtool/ into an android build?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many of the standard libraries are 'missing' from the Android NDK most likely for technical reasons of which I am not aware. I do believe in the release notes for the NDK there are entries for those standard C libraries which are not currently incorporated there might be a mention in there as to why ltdl. I can only suggest to get the source and create an Android NDK project and build it that way. Although may I ask why you need the dynamic loader.. android loads libraries as required anyway (so I understand in my limited knowledge)

Comment: The library that I'm trying to build needs ltdl to build properly.  I haven't found much to explain the lack of it but my general impression is if it's not there, it's not something you can rely on to work, unfortunately.  Do you remember where exactly you saw the list of not-incorporated C libs?

Comment: I was thinking of the file 'android-ndk-root/docs/SYSTEM-ISSUES.html'. I'm no expert in this area but does the library you need to build rely on other libraries? Are you getting errors when you build? If so could you post the errors?